# Java, webdriver, phatom.js unable to find element ajax call - response on the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, remotewebdriver, phantom-reference

First I want to say thanks for read and thanks for possible solutions.

I have problem to find element after ajax call - response on the page. I use Java, webdriver and phantom.js as tools.

In my case phantom.js can access webelement only if I have iframe on the page.

If I haven't frame and wait for ajax response, phantom.js search for element on blank page.

My question is, how to wait for all contet from ajax response without iframe using selenium webdriver, java and phantom.js? Or how phantom.js search element during ajax response. With Chrome driver my test works fine.

Before this question I reaseach possible answers on stackoverflow, google, but i didn't find adequate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wait (e.g. Thread.sleep(25000) for Ajax to finish or you can take a look at https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js